# Codeigniter displaying ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm a Codeigniter noob. I've been trying for quite some time now to solve this. I have a textview in my view.php. On button press, I want to send the text to server (php file) , process it and display result on page. My current code is:

javascript in view:

```
function verify(){
                var posttext = $('#post_text').text();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "http://localhost/naloga1/CodeIgniter/index.php/usercontroller/checkinput",
                    cache: false,               
                    data: {post_text : posttext },
                    success: function(json){                        
                    try{        
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                        alert( obj['STATUS']);


                    }catch(e) {     
                        alert('Exception while request..');
                    }       
                    },
                    error: function(){                      
                        alert('Error while request..');
                    }
             });
        }
```

usercontroller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserController extends CI_Controller {


    public function checkinput(){
        $status = array("STATUS"=>"false");
        $text =  $_POST['post_text'];
        if ($text != null){
            $status = array("STATUS"=>"true");  
        }
        echo json_encode ($status) ;
        $output = $text.strip_tags();
        echo "<p>".$output."</p>";
    }   
}
```

and my textview

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="25" id="post_text" >Some random text</textarea>
    <input type="submit"  id="post_bttn" value="Post" onclick="verify()">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: echo json_encode ($status) ;
        $output = $text.strip_tags();
        echo "<p>".$output."</p>";
  
  why are you echo two times

Comment: I didn't know there was anything wrong with that? is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are not passing any parameter to your Ajax request. Your Data would be

```
 data: {post_text:$('#post_text').text()},
```

And in controller file Use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) like below

```
 $output = strip_tags($text,'<br><br/>');
```

Comment: Thank you, apparently this was my first mistake, but it still throws me an error..

Comment: alert('Exception while request..'); This part of js appears (a window with this text)

Comment: Thank you, but it still throws me the same exception. This is weird.

Comment: Now problem is with try `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                    alert( obj['STATUS']);` just `alert(json);` on it and check

Comment: `try{        
            alert(json);


            }` and check the result

Comment: This doesn't throw exception, displays something like STATUS=true and <p>input text </p>, but the processed text doesn't appear on site yet.

Comment: Now you understand where is your problem left. Try to make your json correct and  then parse also use $ in please of Jquery `$.parseJSON(json);`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach.

Comment: Also add `dataType: 'json',` into ajax because you return json data

Answer (score 2):

```
function verify(){
        var posttext = $('#post_text').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/naloga1/CodeIgniter/index.php/usercontroller/checkinput",
            cache: false,               
            data: {post_text : posttext },
            success: function(json){                        
            try{        
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                alert( obj['STATUS']);


            }catch(e) {     
                alert('Exception while request..');
            }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
     });
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it throws me the Exception while request error, am I missing something?

Comment: I dont't get any error apart from this javascript alert

Comment: $output = $text.strip_tags(); echo "<p>".$output."</p>"; this thing is not encode in json, so you need to encode it and try to keep all in one echo only encode everything and only echo for one time